# draw a picture by latex

Tags: draw

I would like to draw the following graph in the image with LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? If you show a compilable example of what you tried, it will really help others to help you! And you will receive more help this way

Comment: I suppose there is no point to close this as there are already answers with upvotes. Let this sink and we are fine again.

Comment: Please, stop the edits

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.2,-0.4)(6.2,2.6)\sffamily
    \psset{dimen=middle, linejoin=1}
    \psaxes[yAxis=false, linewidth=0pt, tickstyle=top, labels=none, linejoin=1](0,0)(0,0)(6,1)
    \psframe(0,1)(6,0)
    \foreach \i in {0,1,4,6}{\psline(\i, 1)(\i, 0) \uput{3pt}[d](\i, 0){\i}}
    \pnodes{A}(0,1)(1,1)(4,1)(6,1)
    \psset{labelsep=1pt}
    \ncarc[arcangle=35]{A0}{A2}\naput[npos=0.3]{4}
    \ncarc[arcangle=55]{A0}{A3}\naput{6}
    \ncarc[arcangle=45]{A1}{A3}\nbput{5}
    \psset{linestyle=none}
    \ncline{A0}{A1}\nbput{1}
    \ncline{A1}{A2}\nbput{3}
    \ncline{A2}{A3}\nbput{2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun using Ti*K*z.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0)--(6,0)--(6,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
 \foreach \x in {1,...,5}{
 \draw (\x,0)--++(90:0.25);}
 \foreach \x in {1,4}{
 \draw (\x,0)--++(90:1);}
 \foreach \x in {0,1,4,6}{
 \node at (\x,-0.2){\x};}
 \foreach \x/\t in {0.5/1,2.5/3,5/2}{
 \node at (\x,0.8){\t};}
 \path (0,1)  edge   [bend left=25]   node[above=1mm, left=6mm] {4} (4,1);
 \path (1,1)  edge   [bend left=25]   node[above=1.5mm, left=3mm] {5} (6,1);
 \path (0,1)  edge   [bend left=40]   node[above, left=10mm] {6} (6,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun using mathcha with `iwona` font. *PS User without MWE*.

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
First word
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw    (100,129.2) -- (368.5,129.2) (145,125.2) -- (145,133.2)(190,125.2) -- (190,133.2)(235,125.2) -- (235,133.2)(280,125.2) -- (280,133.2)(325,125.2) -- (325,133.2) ;
%Shape: Square [id:dp6094930652284849] 
\draw   (100,84.7) -- (144.5,84.7) -- (144.5,129.2) -- (100,129.2) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp375122879762261] 
\draw   (144.36,85) -- (280.36,85) -- (280.36,129.2) -- (144.36,129.2) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp31151300443341423] 
\draw   (280.36,85) -- (368.36,85) -- (368.36,129.2) -- (280.36,129.2) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp47364655068525563] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (280.72,84.13) .. controls (269.63,59.54) and (234.2,41.14) .. (191.9,40.41) .. controls (147.56,39.65) and (110.09,58.54) .. (100.07,84.59) -- (190.88,99.52) -- cycle ; \draw   (280.72,84.13) .. controls (269.63,59.54) and (234.2,41.14) .. (191.9,40.41) .. controls (147.56,39.65) and (110.09,58.54) .. (100.07,84.59) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp4187809953512516] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (367.8,83.99) .. controls (356.78,55.41) and (311.89,33.44) .. (257.8,32.51) .. controls (200.75,31.52) and (153.11,54.28) .. (144.43,84.87) -- (256.7,96.28) -- cycle ; \draw   (367.8,83.99) .. controls (356.78,55.41) and (311.89,33.44) .. (257.8,32.51) .. controls (200.75,31.52) and (153.11,54.28) .. (144.43,84.87) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp5908366205988349] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (368.35,86.98) .. controls (357.24,52.66) and (302.25,25.86) .. (235.62,24.7) .. controls (167.62,23.53) and (110.8,49.48) .. (100.11,84.48) -- (234.36,98.12) -- cycle ; \draw   (368.35,86.98) .. controls (357.24,52.66) and (302.25,25.86) .. (235.62,24.7) .. controls (167.62,23.53) and (110.8,49.48) .. (100.11,84.48) ;

% Text Node
\draw (95,135.26) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (139,135.26) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (273,133.26) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$4$};
% Text Node
\draw (361,133.26) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$6$};
% Text Node
\draw (117,87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (205,87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$3$};
% Text Node
\draw (319,87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$2$};
% Text Node
\draw (136,50) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$4$};
% Text Node
\draw (258,36.26) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$5$};
% Text Node
\draw (194,7.26) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$6$};
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A special drawing.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]